# Unable to get links to the articles in Python web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I tried everything I could think of. How do I fix this?

Here is What I am trying to do:

1. Scrape categories names & Get categories links and follow them.
2. Scrape Novels' names and follow their links.
3. Scrape Novels' info and their chapters.
4. Open each chapter and scrape the Article with images.

I am a complete beginner...

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

site = "https://readlightnovel.org/"
r = get(site, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
category = soup.findAll(class_="search-by-genre")

#Getting all categories
categories = []
for link in soup.findAll(href=re.compile(r'/category/\w+$')):
  print("Category:", link.text)
  category_link = site + "category/" + link.text
  categories.append(category_link)
  #break

  #Getting all Novel Headers
  for category in categories:
    r = get(category_link, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
    Novels_header = soup.findAll(class_="top-novel-header")

    #Getting Novels' Title and Link
    for Novel_names in Novels_header:
      print(Novel_names.text)
      r = get(Novel_names, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"})
      soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
      Novel_link = soup.findAll("a", {"href"})
      print(Novel_link.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there. Your pulling the text, not the url with `category_link = site + "category/" + link.text`

if you print `'link`', you'll see `<a href="https://www.readlightnovel.org/category/action">Action</a>`

you'd probably be better off getting the `href` as opposed to the text. if the text doesn't match, then you have an unknown link.

Secondly, you need the links from the Novels_header, which is already there....no need to make another request (which wouldn't work anyway as you are not actually feeding in an url at that point).

Give this a try, and see wher eI made the edits:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

site = "https://readlightnovel.org/"
r = get(site, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
category = soup.findAll(class_="search-by-genre")

#Getting all categories
categories = []
for link in soup.findAll(href=re.compile(r'/category/\w+$')):
    print("Category:", link.text)
    category_link = link['href'] #<--- made edit here
    categories.append(category_link)
    #break

#Getting all Novel Headers
for category in categories:
    r = get(category_link, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
    Novels_header = soup.findAll(class_="top-novel-header")

    #Getting Novels' Title and Link
    for Novel_names in Novels_header:     #<---- edit in this block
        print(Novel_names.text.strip())
        Novel_link = Novel_names.find('a')['href']
        print(Novel_link + '\n')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Code worked. Now its time to understand code. <3